# Login failed for user 'SAMUEL-DESKTOP\samfl'

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database-connection

I can access my server and my databases from the software SQL Server Management Studio but when I want to access it by a nodejs app I have an error :

```
ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'SAMUEL-DESKTOP\samfl'.
    at C:\Users\samfl\Desktop\nodejsapi\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:70:17
    at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\samfl\Desktop\nodejsapi\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1012:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Connection.emit (C:\Users\samfl\Desktop\nodejsapi\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1040:18)
    at C:\Users\samfl\Desktop\nodejsapi\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2519:18
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ELOGIN',
  originalError: ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'SAMUEL-DESKTOP\samfl'.
      at Login7TokenHandler.onErrorMessage (C:\Users\samfl\Desktop\nodejsapi\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\handler.js:245:19)
      at Readable.<anonymous> (C:\Users\samfl\Desktop\nodejsapi\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:26:33)
      at Readable.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
      at next (node:internal/streams/from:98:31)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
    code: 'ELOGIN',
    isTransient: undefined
  }
}
```

I tried to change my username
I have seen videos where config has a password but from SSMS I don't have to have one to connect my local server.

[Screenshot from SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHbQ9.png)

My files :

```
// dbconfig.js
const config = {
    user: 'SAMUEL-DESKTOP\\samfl',
    server: 'SAMUEL-DESKTOP',
    database: 'ProductsTestDB',
    // option: {
    //  trustedconnection: true,
    //  enableArithAort: true,
    // },
    trustServerCertificate: true,
    port: 1433,
};

module.exports = config;
```

```
// dboperations.js

let config = require('./dbconfig');
const sql = require('mssql');

async function getProducts() {
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let products = sql.request().query('SELECT * FROM Products');
        return products.recordsets;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = { getProducts: getProducts };
```

```
// api.js
const dboperations = require('./dboperations');
let db = require('./dboperations');
let Product = require('./product');

dboperations.getProducts().then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: You have `trustedconnection: true` commented out - did you try using that and then get rid of it, or...? If you use that setting, it will use Windows Authentication (i.e. it uses your Windows login information as the login information for the SQL server), which I think is what you want.

Comment: When you specify a username or password in your connection properties you're telling the driver to use SQL Logon authentication. Since SQL Logon sever logins are different from Windows server logins (SQL Logons are local to the SQL Server instance) you cannot authenticate as a Windows user by way of SQL Logon authentication. Have you tried commenting out the `user` property and uncommenting the `trustedConnection: true` option? NOTE: Javascript is case sensitive, so it's `trustedConnection` with a `C`. Is the Node process running in the context of the `SAMUEL-DESKTOP\samfl` Windows account?